# Expression in ASP.NET Core TagHelpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In TagHelpers we usually have a property called **asp-for** to connect the TagHelper to a Model property.

I created a custom TagHelper, and added a property like a asp-for:

```
    [HtmlTargetElement("myinput", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
    public class MyInputTagHelper : TagHelper {
        public ModelExpression Field { get; set; }
    }
```

Normally, if the bound model is a complex type with subclasses and I need the full path to that property, I can get the full access path by evaluating *System.Linq.Expressions.Expression*. How can I achive this with ModelExpression?

I Have a model:

```
public class PersonVM
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

and in .cshtml:

```
@model PersonVM

<myinput field="Person.PersonAddress.City"/>
```

In the TagHelper *MyInputTagHelper*, I need the full request path. In this example it would be "Person.PersonAddress.City". All I could get is "City" via *Field.Metadata.PropertyName*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it, the original expression is saved in

```
ModelExpression.Name
```